# Python/Django Query to check if Dates Overlap

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set up a validation on an API built with Python/Django. I'm using a serializer and would like to do a query filter against the post data to make sure 2 date fields do not overlap.
For example: My Post contains:

`"valid_start": "2021-09-01",`
`"valid_end": "2021-09-15"`

I would like to an object.filter to check if there are any records in my database with overlapping dates:
I want to throw a validation error if the query detects any of the following

`"valid_start": "2021-09-01",`
`"valid_end": "2021-09-15"`

`"valid_start": "2021-09-02",`
`"valid_end": "2021-09-15"`

`"valid_start": "2021-09-03",`
`"valid_end": "2021-09-10"`

`"valid_start": "2021-08-28",`
`"valid_end": "2021-09-20"`

I've tried the __range function, gte/lte functions, none really do what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I assume these are `date` fields? Not strings, right?

Comment: Do these overlap if they share the "boundaries", like one ending at `2021-9-16` and another beginning at `2021-9-16`?

Comment: They are date fields

Answer (score 2):

Let us first determine when two date ranges do *not* overlap. These do not overlap if *end<sub>1</sub> < start<sub>2</sub>* or *end<sub>2</sub> < start<sub>1</sub>*. The opposite of this condition is *end<sub>1</sub> ≥ start<sub>2</sub>* and *end<sub>2</sub> ≥ start<sub>1</sub>*, we thus can query with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    valid_end__gte=valid_start,
    valid_start__lte=valid_end
)
```

Where `valid_start` and `valid_end` are thus the start and end dates you want to insert. If such record exists, then you try to insert a record with at least some overlap. If no such record is found through filtering, it will not overlap with the new record you are creating.

Comment: This was so obvious I don't know why I didn't think of it lol thank you!